Converting JSON API responses to DataFrame
I have connected to the API and have gotten a response, but have difficulty converting the JSON into a dataframe for me to work on in Python, despite trying the solutions given in similar problems posted. Will greatly appreciate any help on this pls.
I had tried the following but had received the following error:

"KeyError: 'records'".

import requests
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd
from pandas import json_normalize 
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

          
base_url = "https://data.gov.sg/api/action/datastore_search"
url = base_url + "?resource_id=d_8575e84912df3c28995b8e6e0e05205a"
response = requests.get(url).json()
df = pd.json_normalize(response,'records')
print(df)



The records are actually nested inside another result key:
{
    "help": "https://data.gov.sg/api/3/action/help_show?name=datastore_search",
    "success": true,
    "result": {
        "resource_id": "d_8575e84912df3c28995b8e6e0e05205a",
        "fields": [...],
        "records": [
            {
                ...
            }
        ],
        "_links": {
            "start": "/api/action/datastore_search?resource_id=d_8575e84912df3c28995b8e6e0e05205a",
            "next": "/api/action/datastore_search?resource_id=d_8575e84912df3c28995b8e6e0e05205a&offset=100"
        },
        "total": 160137
    }
}

Try this code:
import requests
import pandas as pd
          
base_url = "https://data.gov.sg/api/action/datastore_search"
url = base_url + "?resource_id=d_8575e84912df3c28995b8e6e0e05205a"
response = requests.get(url).json()
df = pd.json_normalize(response["result"],'records')
print(df)

